# Background color for a text

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to give background to a text in html but i'm stuck.

i've tried the code below:

```
<p><span style="background-color: #000;color:#fff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt bibendum ligula, ac pulvinar justo scelerisque in. Ut nec auctor urna.</span></p>
```

result is:

[image: first result]

that is what i want to do (like selected-text):

[image: want to do]

don't know how to do that. any helps would be great.

thanks!

Comment: Put your text in a div...

Comment: Have you try to use a div instead of span ? span are one line element

Comment: Do **not** use inline css, it's utterly unflexible and .. **ugh** inline css. Use stylesheets or at least a style tag.

Comment: have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k3o62c6o/

Comment: @Tarekis: inline CSS is perfectly valid and in some cases I'd recommend it. Imagine you have a very specific page element  that doesn't appear anywhere else, on a page that is averagely frequented. The style tag doesn't add much to readability or performance and you wouldn't want to add this to a globally used CSS file as that would mean lots of redundant code and downloading on other pages. Especially for temporary pages like special offers or limited landing pages inline styles are perfect. Even for temporary special elements in pages. This makes removal easier and lowers redundancy-hassle.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I can see your point yes, but in any other case, just as soon as JS reference to this element is needed, a ID would be the better option, if this element is used more than once, all other enviorment variables you mentioned unchanged, a class in a local css would be the better option. Probably this situation does apply to the OP's situation, i assume - like many newer WebDevs - Op just uses one piece of code not exporting code to thier proper destinations, hence telling him to not use inline-css is a good advice imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is what you're trying to do.

You need to make the paragraph `inline`**(which will keep the black only behind your text and not overflow)**, then apply a small amount of `padding` and `line-height` to your paragraph so the lines touch and look nice.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt bibendum ligula, ac pulvinar justo scelerisque in. Ut nec auctor urna.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

let me explain you what you need to do...
the style which you gave to **span** tag remove it and give it to **" P "** tag, this will solve your problem.

So what you will get it like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) ;color:#fff; display: inline; padding: .4em; line-height: 140%;"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt bibendum ligula, ac pulvinar justo scelerisque in. Ut nec auctor urna.</span></p>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: p is a block element, so this will add a black rectangle.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak right, it will add a black rectangle, but it will surely result in a given output. :)

Comment: Now with the display:inline you added it will work, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the transparency use `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` where the last value is the amount of transparency.

This is not supported by IE8 unfortunately http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba. You can use `filter` for IE 8 http://rland.me.uk/cross-browser-alpha-transparent-background-10-2011/

Also to get the full block of colour put your style onto the p tag and not the span.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt bibendum ligula, ac pulvinar justo scelerisque in. Ut nec auctor urna.</p>

p {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color:#fff;
  display: inline;
}
```

With a transparent background you can get issues with the colour overlaying and being darker between lines, you can play around with `line-height:` to fix this.

Comment: Adding a background color on a block element will result in a rectangular background, BTW. You need to either use an inline element or set display:inline.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I missed the `display: inline;` I thought i had put that in.

Answer (score 0):

try this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xm4sLch8/1/ or apply below css to your span:

```
span{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

We can provide `line-height`, `background` instead of `background-color` to apply background transparency with same effect